# GitHub OAuth Application variable redirect_uri

Tags: php, github, oauth

I am working on a PHP Application which uses **github oauth**. It will be available for everyone to download and use. Users will use it on their own web hosting domains.

The problem is that I cannot set a fixed redirect uri for all of them.

How should I set things up so that the users are able to use my application wherever they install. The OAuth authentication response should always redirect to the origin of the request.

[Github OAuth Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth)
[Register a new OAuth application at Github](https://github.com/settings/applications/new)

For my specific case, if that matters, only a single user will authorise via Github per installation.